# CakePHP showing include_once warnings

Tags: php, cakephp, classloader, directory-structure

Suddenly, this website stop working and this errors appeared:

**Warning:** include_once(///controllers/site/default.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/var/www/html/sitename.com/web/index.php** on line **54**

**Warning:** include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '///controllers/site/default.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in **/var/www/html/sitename.com/web/index.php** on line **54**

I don't know how CakePHP works, this is why I need help to figure out what happened (without anyone messing the code). The indicated files, that says that they're not there (No such file or directory), are exactly where the path describes.

I appreciate any help!

**Error from line 54 in index.php:**

```
include_once sprintf('%s/%s%s/%s.php', ROOT_PROJECT, CONTROLLERS_DIR, $url->tipo, 'default');
```

Comment: What's the code generating the issue? (index.php line 54)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to quote that. Just edited de code.

Comment: `///controllers/site/default.php` is wrong path. Your problem maybe happens because of `%s`es are blank?

Comment: What CakePHP version is this?

Comment: Yes, I think that this is where the problem relies... But I still can't figure this out. When I type for www.sitename.com/web/index.php, the errors changes. There are no include errors, but it's weird how this website was working perfectly once. The server root is also weird, 'cause there are only folders: web, tmp, logs and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the variables inserted through sprintf.

There are some empty ones causing a lot of backslashes to be added to the string;

Basically it says

```
include('///controllers/site/default.php');
```

(This is also visible in the generated php warning)

Try catching empty variables or parsing the resulting string (making sure only 1 backslash exists between every parameter).

If I'm right the next php command should work:

```
include('/controllers/site/default.php');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fyntasia, how exactly should I do this?

Comment: This is actually very dependant on the rest of your code. I don't know what happens in the rest of your code and I don't know which variables come from where. You could try checking each variable individually with a simple (empty($var)) and make sure it does not generate an extra backslash.

Comment: When I directly type "controllers/site/default.php" in the include which is the right path, it shows a blank page...

Comment: I can really only tell you what's CAUSING the error, with that, the ball is in your court to fix it. Sorry I can't help you any further.

Comment: It's okay, that was really helpful. I appreciate yout attention!

Comment: Great, I hope it helped you towards fixing the problem in your code! Good luck!